# Error con un if múltiple

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num1;
    cout<<"Ingrese un numero: ";
    cin>>num1;
    if (num1>0 && num1<100) {
        num1%10==4;
        cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
    }
    else if (num1>100 && num1<1000) {
        num1%100==4;
        cout<<"El numero termina en 4. ";
    }
    else if (num1>1000 && num1<10000) {
        num1%1000==4;
        cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
    }
    else{
            (cout<<"El numero no termina en cuatro.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Soy novato, buenas tardes. 
Necesito que este programa me diga si un número cualquiera termina en cuatro (4) o no, el problema es que independiente del último dígito siempre me dice que termina en cuatro (4). En qué estoy fallando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

felicidades vas muy bien, solo que dentro de los if o los if-else debes de meter otro if, para poder hacer la comparación y verificar si termina en 4 entonces:

```
num1%10==4;
```

debería quedar como

```
if(num1%10==4)
{ cout << "El numero termina en 4"}
else
{ cout << "El numero NO termina en 4"}
```

Otra cosa, si haces el modulo "%" sobre 10 directamente no necesitas ir haciendo tantos casos, ni haces tan redundante tu código;

24984 % 10 = 4
24983 % 10 != 4

Answer (score 1):

```
num1%100==4;
cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
```

Esta expresión compara `num%100` con `4` y devuelve `true` o `false`, pero no hace nada con ese valor. Si lo que quieres es que haga algo, lo tienes que poner dentro de un `if`

```
if (num1%10==4) {
  cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
}
```

o, teniendo encuenta el resto de tu código

```
if (num1>0 && num1<100 && num1%10==4) {
```

Luego está la cuestión de que no entiendes muy bien qué hace el operador módulo. Para sacar el digito menos significativo siempre se hace `%10`, no importa lo grande que sea el dividendo. Para que lo entiendas, `%10` te dará un número entre `0` y `9`, `%100` un número entre `0` y `99`, `%1000` un número entre `0` y `999`....

Por ejemplo, al hacer `4124%1000` obtienes `124`, que obviamente no es igual a `4`.

Es decir, no necesitas tantos `if` y tantos casos especiales. Sólo una operación de módulo, una comparación, y un `if`.

Answer (score 1):

**Buen día**

En tu código solo estas evaluando rango:

```
if (num1>0 && num1<N)
```

dentro de eso a continuación tienes:

```
num1%10==4;
```

lo anterior no lo estas evaluando (alguna sentencia selectiva); y la instrucción que tienes seguido es imprirmi a pantalla en mensaje siempre con:

```
cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
```

te falta evaluar; si la intención de tu código la entiendo debe ser:

```
if ((num1%10)==4) /* Esto para el primer "if (num1>0 && num1<100)" completa los demás según corresponda */
    cout<<"El numero termina en 4.";
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, pude entender perfectamente.